# MySQL group by trick to exclude coupling

Tags: mysql

I have these tables in my db

TELEPHONE CALLS(
caller, called, date, time, ......., weight)

TELEPHONE_NUMBERS
(number, .......)

I need a query where I select all single telephone calls between two numbers.
So far I ve selected the numbers and grouped them by caller, caller

The problem is that this will not eliminate doublicates because for example

A -> B

And B -> A are considered different

Normally I would escape that coupling by using something like

HAVING caller-called<0

That would only leave me with the unique communications between two numbers. But my telephone numbers are varchar fields.

I thought of casting them to INT but that might be too heavy. Any ideas that would be more efficient?

Also, I would be interested in keep the max weight value for each telephone call.

To give you a complete example

the number 69782 calls 69783 (69782 -> 69783) and this calls weight is 0.8
then the same numbers communicate again (69783 -> 69782) with a weight of 0.5

So I want to select all the unique communication records between them ( I dont care about the numbers being callers or called I just want to see their connection) with the maximum weight!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can use `varchar` fields in a numeric context, so the

```
HAVING caller-called<0
```

will work unless you have non-digit chars in this field.

Comment: Yeah, I was ready to edit that, it seems you are right and since I ensured I have NO non digits it works fine. Thanks alot!!!

Comment: Thinking this through It must be noted however that if you have a single record that is not coupled and caller is < than called then you lose that record completelly.